# Entity Framework Core: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm using Entity Framework Core, and cannot insert an explicit value for the identity column in table

DBContext:

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<TbUser>(entity =>
            {
                entity.Property(e => e.Jid)
                    .HasColumnName("JID")
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
}
```

TBUser:

```
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Jid { get; set; }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It's not clear what is the problem from your question. You have to provide more details.

Comment: I'm trying to add data to database. I cannot add data because there is an identity column on the table.

Comment: An identity value is generated automatically if you use `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]`. If you want to use your own value then you must generate an explicit value as part of the save and know that it is unique. I suspect there is a conflict with `ValueGeneratedOnAdd` and you should have one or the other but not both. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties).

Answer (score 2):

In your EF model code, you're defining the column `Jid` as `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]`

This tells entity framework that the *database will generate a value for this field*. Logically then, you should not set the value in code.

If you want to manually set the values in this field you need to remove the `DatabaseGenerated` decorator above.

Comment: This will require model changes and migrations.

Comment: @matcheek Its his app, he can make those changes while he's learning how EF works and interacts with the database.

Comment: @GaryStewart That's only a good advice if he's working alone on project. In any other production-aspiring environment pushing EF model changes without migrations it's a no-no.

Comment: @matcheek I dont think Gary is suggesting that you're wrong, just that this anwsers the question in isolation - which is generally a good principle for SO otherwise we'd get stuck into specific implementation details all the time, e.g. how the migrations are handled depends on his specific project setup. Probably not worth diving into team structures as well :)

Comment: I want an automated id. I'm still getting the same mistake.

Comment: I wanna insert to database with identity id

Comment: @SteveLand well the simplest possible solution is to turn off identity insert. And changing the schema with new models and migrations is way more complex. Clearly OP cannot handle the solution you provided. And frankly, that's only a good solution for a homework (what happened to homework tag) not involving any production code :)

Comment: @squirrelx3 remove `.ValueGeneratedOnAdd()` you dont need it. As @Steve Land has said `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` will suffice

Comment: I fix like this; UseSqlServerIdentityColumn()

Answer (score -5):

Make sure the `IDENTITY_INSERT` is off.
That way the identities for every insert will need to be provided explicitly.

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [ [ database_name . ] schema_name . ] table_name { ON | OFF }
```

[More details on Identity_insert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Turning that off at the DB level when he's got it set at the EF level doesn't make sense.

Comment: Did you bother to run the profiler? There is no way EF would be allowed to insert identity if you don't make a trip do db and change that on db level in one way or another.

Comment: Profiler for what? I understand how EF works and interacts with the database.

Comment: >Profiler for what?
Ermmm....SQL Profiler? If you understand EF surely you use the SQL Profiler on a daily basis. Other thing is that, as you know, EF would need a migration to make model changes that remove the identity column.